# Which information can I get from osgi console about bundle service?

Tags: java, events, service, osgi, aem

I have osgi bundle(third party):

This bundle has service:

If I click to this service(`http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles`->select bundle->click to the service) I see following information:

```
[org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler, com.adobe.granite.xss.XSSFilter]
    component.id    98
    component.name  com.adobe.granite.xss.impl.XSSFilterImpl
    event.topics    org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource/*
    org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceProvider/*
    Service PID com.adobe.granite.xss.impl.XSSFilterImpl
    Service Vendor  Adobe Systems Incorporated
    Using Bundles   com.adobe.granite.security.user (73)
    com.day.cq.cq-xssprotection (75)
    org.apache.felix.eventadmin (38)
```

I see eventHandler here and I want to know events when this service invokes.

I want to know this code executes at this moment(after event happened)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event.topics service property is standard for OSGi [EventHandler services](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v41/org/osgi/service/event/EventHandler.html), here it tells you that this one is listening for the following OSGi event topics:

- `org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource/*`
- `org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceProvider/*`

If you want to know when such events happen you could register your own `EventHandler` with the same topics, and log messages when those happen - unless your system already provides that info in DEBUG or other logs.

To find out what code the `XSSFilterImpl` executes, you'll need to debug it, as Balazs Zsoldos indicates.

Comment: how to activate these event topics?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "activate". Sling will send OSGi messages with these topics when certain things happen, and you could also send such messages directly but that's not a good idea.

Comment: Can you explain *certain things* ?

Comment: Sorry I missed your question earlier - As mentioned at http://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/how-to-manage-events-in-sling.html the javadocs of the SlingConstants class at http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/SlingConstants.html contain a number of TOPIC_ constants that Sling uses to send events when "certain things" happen. The constant descriptions explain what the events mean.